# ActiveRecord attribute is nil but database has value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

**SOLVED**
There were datetime format issues between Rails and SQLite. After removing time zone entries in config/application.rb this issue cleared up.

I am working with Ruby on Rails, fairly new with Rails. Whenever I query objects, the created_at and updated_at fields are nil on the ruby object.

When I use sqlitebrowser to examine the backend, I can see that the field has a value. I am using **rails console** to figure this out.

```
jwilliam@ubuntu:~/rails/devminder$ rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.8)
2.2.2 :001 > Instance.all
  Instance Load (1.1ms) SELECT "instances".* FROM "instances"
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Instance id: 1, title: "test" ec2id: "", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, can_ice: 0>]>
2.2.2 :002 > SQLite3::Database.new('db/development.sqlite3').execute("select instances.* from instances")
 => [[1,"test", "", "2015-06-29 15:35:10.012611", "2015-06-29 15:35:10.012611", 0]]
```

When I execute **Instance.all** I see that I am getting nil for created_at and updated_at, however executing the query directly to SQLite3 shows that there are values, and it is not mapping them to ActiveRecord attributes properly.

I have a Rails project, using a SQLite3 backend. I am sure I have done something to jam this app up, but I am trying to figure it out.

file **app/models/instance.rb**

```
class Instance < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

file **app/models/schedule.rb**

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
   #table schedules has an instance_id field... 
   belongs_to :instance
end
```

migration **db/migrations/20141216152255_create_instances.rb**

```
class CreateInstances < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :instances do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.string :ec2id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

file **db/migrations/20141230203652_instance_changes.rb**

```
class InstanceChanges < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :instances, :can_ice, :boolean
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you add you migrations as well?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7735

Comment: I have other migrations, but these are the only ones which affect Instancees table. I have some other relations like schedule and lease which belong_to :instance.. Could this be messing with the instance mapping?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I am able to insert records just fine and the dates are appearing in the database.

Comment: `SQLite3::Development.new`? That code works for me but only if I change that to `SQLite::Database.new`. I have build a new app which is a replica of the design you have stated and I can't replicate the issues you are having. Is there anything else you recently changed?

Comment: Yes its a typo, im retyping from my vm due to clipboard issues. The Instances was the first thing I added. Just a start/stop page for users to start and stop AWS EC2 instances from a web form.  I have added several other classes (Schedules, Leases, Deployments) all which have instance_id field.

Comment: What happens if you try to update the `created_at` column in the console? Does the database reflect the change?

Comment: From console
obj = Instance.find(1)
obj.updated_at = Time.now
obj.save

I can see the updated_at value has changed in the sqlite3 database

Comment: What about the `created_at` column though? When you save, `updated_at` is automatically updated. If you can change the `created_at` column though, then we will know that the changes you make are affecting the database directly. I can't come up with anything besides maybe needing to restart your console that could cause this, it is a very odd issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81913/discussion-between-brandon-and-jd-williams).

Comment: If you've solved your own question, submit your solution as an answer and accept it. Don't edit it into your question or title.